# Remove 1 Form from Formset Dynamically Django

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, ajax

I am using the below to dynamically add a form to my formset:

.html

```
{{ form2.management_form }}
      <div id="form_set">
          {% for form2 in form2.forms %}
              <table class="table table2" width=100%>
                <tr>
                  <td width = 17.5%>{{form2.ProductCode}}</td>
                  <td width = 32.5%>{{form2.DescriptionOfGoods}}</td>
                  <td width = 12.5%>{{form2.UnitQty}}</td>
                  <td width = 12.5%>{{form2.Type}}</td>
                  <td width = 12.5%>{{form2.Price}}</td>
                  <td width = 12.5%>{{form2.Amount}}</td>
                </tr>
              </table>
          {% endfor %}
      </div>
      <button id="add_more" class="btn aqua-gradient">Add</button>
      <button id="delete" class="btn aqua-gradient">Delete</button>
      <div id="empty_form" style="display:none">
        <table class='table table2' width=100%>
          <tr>
            <td width = 17.5%>{{form2.empty_form.ProductCode}}</td>
            <td width = 32.5%>{{form2.empty_form.DescriptionOfGoods}}</td>
            <td width = 12.5%>{{form2.empty_form.UnitQty}}</td>
            <td width = 12.5%>{{form2.empty_form.Type}}</td>
            <td width = 12.5%>{{form2.empty_form.Price}}</td>
            <td width = 12.5%>{{form2.empty_form.Amount}}</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>
```

```
$('#add_more').click(function() {
        var counter=0;
        var form_count = $('#id_form-TOTAL_FORMS').val();
        counter++;
        $('#form_set').append($('#empty_form').html().replace(/__prefix__/g, form_count));
        $('#id_form-TOTAL_FORMS').val(parseInt(form_count) + 1);
    });
```

This works perfectly - however I need to be able to delete a line dynamically as well when the Delete button is clicked, and I'm struggling with working through the best way to do that.  Any suggestions? I had tried this below - but of course that will only delete all forms and only if they are empty.  I want to just delete one form at a time.  I feel I may need to add a counter to the id above?  Please any suggestions would be very useful.

```
$('#delete').click(function() {

        var form_idx = $('#id_form-TOTAL_FORMS').val();
        $('#form_set').empty($('#empty_form').html().replace(/__prefix__/g, form_idx));
        $('#id_form-TOTAL_FORMS').val(parseInt(form_idx) - 1);
    });
```

EDIT:

I am currently trying:

```
function removeForm(){
  this.parentElement.remove()
  var form_idx = $('#id_form-TOTAL_FORMS').val();
  $('#id_form-TOTAL_FORMS').val(parseInt(form_idx) - 1);
}

$('#add_more').click(function() {
  var btn = document.createElement("BUTTON");
  console.log(btn)
  $('#id_form-'+(form_count)+'-name')[0].parentElement.appendChild(btn)
  btn.innerHTML = "Remove";
  btn.onclick = removeForm


    var form_count = $('#id_form-TOTAL_FORMS').val();
    $('#form_set').append($('#empty_form').html().replace(/__prefix__/g, form_count));
    $('#id_form-TOTAL_FORMS').val(parseInt(form_count) + 1);

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can add a button to the form and then assing it a function to delete the form add the following to your #add_more function:

```
var btn = document.createElement("BUTTON");
$('#id_form-'+(form_count)+'-name')[0].parentElement.appendChild(btn)    
btn.innerHTML = "Remove";
btn.onclick = removeForm
```

and the removeForm function looks like:

```
function removeForm(){
    this.parentElement.remove()
    var form_idx = $('#id_form-TOTAL_FORMS').val();
    $('#id_form-TOTAL_FORMS').val(parseInt(form_idx) - 1);
}
```

EDIT:

```
$('#add_more').click(function() {
   var form_count = $('#id_form-TOTAL_FORMS').val();
   $('#form_set').append($('#empty_form').html().replace(/__prefix__/g, form_count));
   $('#id_form-TOTAL_FORMS').val(parseInt(form_count) + 1);
   var btn = document.createElement("BUTTON");
   $('#id_form-'+(form_count)+'-name')[0].parentElement.appendChild(btn)
   btn.innerHTML = "Remove";
   btn.onclick = removeForm
});
```

EDIT2 after solving the issue in chat:

the lines:

```
$('#id_form-'+(form_count)+'-name')[0].parentElement.appendChild(btn)
```

and

```
this.parentElement.remove()
```

change significant depending on the structure of your html

the first is to select where to add the button to delete a form and the second is to find the form to delete...

Comment: thank you for your reply - I see that is creating a button but I am now getting the following error in the console: ```Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'parentElement' of undefined
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> ((index):818)
    at HTMLButtonElement.dispatch (jquery-3.4.1.min.js:2)
    at HTMLButtonElement.v.handle (jquery-3.4.1.min.js:2)```

Comment: hmm strange...

i have it running but in the sample i have it also includes bootstrap... 

in the end you can also pass the button object explicitly to the function, i think....

BUT:

is the script at the buttom of the page and the removeForm defined above the  add_more ? i think it might also be an issue about the ordering ...

Comment: I've edited my original question to show how I have things set up in my script right now...does that ordering look correct to you? The script is at the bottom of the page. I see the ```<button>``` in the log only, not actually viewable in the template - as you can see  I was printing it to try to determine if it was being created.

Comment: you need to set the last three lines before the button adding lines i adjusted my answer

Comment: hmm still the same error even with that - so that I'm making sure that I'm clear - is the idea here to append a button in each ```<tr>``` ?

Comment: the idea is to add the button to each form in the formset

Comment: yeah I can print the button it in the console, it just does not show in my template - is there something I am missing that I'm supposed to be adding to my HTML?

Comment: can you for once try to just render the form like {{form2}} and not for each field with the table,i'm not really sure if this is the issue...   i think its only a matter of html to show it properly...

you can try in the browser inspector to check if the button is there and modify it untill you see it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211970/discussion-between-gxm100-and-bb4l).